# Why isn't this 'for loop' exiting? C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm quite a beginner with C, and I'm just wondering why this 'for loop' isn't exiting:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *openfile;
    int notenumber;

    openfile = fopen("test.txt", "w");

        if (openfile == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening file\n");
        }
        else
        {
            for (notenumber=1; notenumber<=16; notenumber++)
            {
                notenumber = aserveGetNote();
                fprintf(openfile, "Notenumber = %d\n", notenumber);         
            }

        }

        fclose(openfile);


    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the loop will not exit. Even if I remove the if else loop and just have the for loop, I still have the same problem?

Comment: Its because of `notenumber = aserveGetNote();` Change the variable name to something else

Comment: `notenumber = aserveGetNote();` : if ` aserveGetNote()` always returns something below 16, the `for` loop can't be completed.

Comment: You  should not call `fclose()` on  a `NULL` pointer, it's undefined behavior, move `fclose()` to the `else` block.

Comment: `if` is not a loop. Loops loop, while `if` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aserveGetNote()` changes the value of `notenumber` to something below 16, so the loop never exits as `notenumber<=16;` is always true.

You can solve the problem by doing like this:

```
int test=aserveGetNote();
fprintf(openfile, "Notenumber = %d\n", test);
// or fprintf(openfile, "Notenumber = %d\n", notenumber); as I don't know which value do you want to store
```

Answer (score 1):

`notenumber = aserveGetNote();` : if `aserveGetNote()` always returns something below 16, the `for` loop can't be completed.

Try

```
for (notenumber=1; notenumber<=16; notenumber++)
        {
            int note = aserveGetNote();
            fprintf(openfile, "Note = %d Notenumber %d\n", note,notenumber);         
        }
```

And follow the advice of @iharob : put `fclose()` in the `else` part of the test, to avoid calling `fclose()` on `NULL`.

Welcome to Stackoverflow !

Answer (score 0):

The question is already answered. One more hint: You do check after `fopen` for `NULL`. but what would happen if you do get a `NULL` and call `fclose`? On my machine I get a segmentation fault error.